# How to set default lambda function for named lambda argument with generics in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, lambda, kotlin, anonymous-function, named-parameters

This code prints "Hello 1". `parseInput` have two generic types, the first arg is a simple object of the first generic type A, the second arg is a function which suppose to change the generic type A to generic B. As you can see it works fine in the following.

```
fun toGreeting(input : Int) : String {
    return "hello " + input
}

fun <A, B> parseInput(raw : A, toB : (raw : A) -> B) : B {
    return toB(raw)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val greeting = parseInput(1, ::toGreeting)
    println(greeting)
}
```

The question is how can I give a default lambda value for the second named argument in the `parseInput`. So I can call this function by just providing the first argument, and having it to use the default lambda function.

```
val greeting = parseInput(1)
println(greeting)
```

Comment: What do you want to specify as the default value? The default value can only be a function from Any to Any, and there are not too many useful functions which fit this signature.

Comment: It seems like you can't even have an `(Any) -> Any` function as the default here. Since there's generics involved, a generic `(A) -> B` function is required, which then forces the caller to specify the generic types, as there's no way to infer `B`. As for the implementation of this default function, you can either cast something to `B` inside it (which _probably_ won't succeed), or have it return `Nothing` (which is not what you want here).

Comment: @yole, a void, Unit would be good for default value.

Comment: So you want `greeting` in your second example to be equal to `Unit`? How is that useful?

Comment: @yole, right it's not useful, but I wanted it to be not useful if it isn't provided when calling the function. My goal is to make the second function optional, which is why I want a default lambda function to return Unit

Comment: What if you made the second parameter nullable, assigned `null` to it as a default, and then returned `toB?.invoke(raw)` ?

Comment: @zsmb13 Error:(16, 19) Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter B in fun <A, B> parseInput(raw: A, toB: ((raw: A) -> B)? = ...): B?
Please specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are contradictory. You want to be able to specify a function that returns a value of type B for any B (which is actually impossible by itself; the only possible such function is a function that always throws an exception), and you also want the compiler to be able to infer what B is when you haven't given the compiler any information from which it can be determined. In your example:

```
 val greeting = parseInput(1)  
 println(greeting)
```

...there is zero information from which the compiler could determine what type the `greeting` variable needs to have. There is no logic that would substitute `Unit` or any other specific type in this case; instead, as you correctly remark in your comment, this code fails to compile.

If you want `greeting` to be `Unit` in this case, you can achieve this by simply overloading the function:

```
fun <A> parseInput(raw: A) {
}
```

This function will return `Unit`, giving you the exact behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Overloading would work, but it is not what I am looking for. If I have some other logics need to be processed in this `parseInput`? I will have to duplicate them in the overloading functions. I could move the common logics into another function which can be called in the overloading functions `parseInput`, but that's not what I would like to do either.

Comment: `parseInput(1, ::toGreeting)` works because toGreeting is providing the type to be returned. You are right that `parseInput(1)` fails because there is no type provided to the compiler to infer what B is. So this points back to the question, is there a way to provide a default function like toGreeting in the function signature?

Comment: There is no way to specify a default function in such a way that the compiler would take the type arguments from that default function.

Comment: It would be nice if there is a way to do so!

Comment: Just chiming in here that being able to do `fun <A, B> parseInput(raw : A, toB : (raw : A) -> B = { it }) : B {}` would be great, in which case it would be clear that B is the same type as A.